# Unable to read packets captured from wifi network using wireshark

Tags: linux, wifi, wireshark

I am connected to my home wifi network using Ubuntu 10.10. The protection is WPA2-auto.
I want to capture packets from it.

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
$ sudo wireshark
```

I try to capture from `wlan0`.
Am connected to the wifi network with an android phone and browsing websites.
However I am unable to see unencrypted http packets.

I select Edit|Preferences|Capture|Protocols
and select 802.11 and set the checkbox to yes for 'decrypt packets'.
Still nothing.

Comment: I also tried disabling wifi protection at the router config screen. This time, there were no packets at all.

Comment: This is not really programming related.

Comment: I disagree. On the pane to the right, I see lots of wireshark questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: run `airmon-ng` from the aircrack-ng project to set the wireless card into monitor mode. (this was pointed out by a Wireshark developer on the mailing lists). Apparently `iwconfig` does not work properly as it has issues on Ubuntu.

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

This will set it into monitor mode and create interface `mon0`.

After this, I was able to capture off the `mon0` interface using Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

You must capture the association sequence to be able to decrypt the traffic.
If you start your capture when the phone is already connected then Wireshark
cannot decrypt the packets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried again ensuring that I performed the above steps before connecting to the wifi network from my phone.

I see only mdns packets. They are unencrypted - perhaps they are being decrypted correctly.

In the details pane, I see they are Queries: type PTR, class IN, "QM" question
I browse to a web server from my phone on the same network. I bring up the website (http clear, not https). I browse successfully, but do not see any http packets in wireshark.

    5 96.017187 10.42.43.1 224.0.0.251 MDNS    Standard query PTR _sane-port._tcp.local, "QM" question

Comment: ...continued. To troubleshoot, I try switching the channel from 1,2,3 since in Wifi Analyzer on my phone, I can see that the network occupies channels 0-3

sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 1

Still does not work.

Comment: I upvoted the reply - however the problem remains. anyone have any insight into this?