# Can't see WiFi traffic from my mobile in Wireshark?

Tags: android, windows, ubuntu, wireshark

So, I'm running Ubuntu Linux on my laptop, and Android 4.0.4 on my mobile (I don't think this is relevant, but just in case). I've got my laptop unassociated from any networks, and my mobile is on my network and has been assigned (by DHCP) the IP of 192.168.0.109.

On my laptop, I did this:
`ifconfig wlan0 down && airmon-ng start wlan0 && ifconfig wlan0 up` .. this created my `mon0` interface for promiscuous mode, if I'm not mistaken.

I fired up Wireshark, attached it to `mon0` and assigned a **display** filter of `ip.addr == 192.168.0.109`, go back to my mobile, and navigate to a few websites. I get absolutely nothing.

The step listed here - [unable to read packets captured from wifi network using wireshark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242451/unable-to-read-packets-captured-from-wifi-network-using-wireshark) - do not help either.

Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? :(

Thanks!

Comment: _"I've got my laptop unassociated from any networks,"_ I believe this is the cause, you don't need create another interface `mon0`, when you browse website on mobile, it doesn't use this fake network interface `mon0 `. Just make sure your laptop and mobile are connected to the same network which has access to internet.

Comment: Are you sure your wireless card can enter monitor (or promiscuous) mode?

Comment: @yorkw - My laptop is unassociated, but I do believe I need a promiscuous interface - if not, my card will just ignore any traffic that's actually meant for the router -- wouldn't it? (I'm pretty sure this is **the** reason for putting a card in promiscuous mode

Comment: @DelusionalLogic - I am positive, though I unfortunately _neglected_ to say that I'm getting spammed by Broadcasts from all around me, and seeing other traffic that I'm not really too keen on. Having that information handy might have saved us the effort of this quip :P My apologies!
(I posted this while Wireshark has been running, and I'm well over 50k packets captured thus far.. I just can't figure out how to filter it :()

Comment: Just had an idea, that maybe my laptop can't see the IP address because it's not associated? I tried `eth.addr == 2c:44:01:xx:xx:xx` to try to filter by MAC, but that didn't give me any results either..

Comment: What WiFi type (802.11b/802.11g, etc.), encryption (e.g. WPA2), and wireless card are you using?

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen - It's 802.11 b/g, channel 1, It's WPA/WPA2. I'm using my built in wifi chipset in my laptop, which is an Atheros chip - AR9285. I'm figuring the data would be encrypted, but ... I should still _see_ it, right? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I was having was that the wifi card I was using wasn't giving errors when I switched modes, but it didn't support them none-the-less.

Using another card worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Set the WPA or WPA2 key by going to:

1. Edit » Preferences
2. Protocols
3. IEEE 802.11
4. Enable decryption
5. Enter the WPA or WPA2 key in Key #1 or the next field, or in more recent versions use the "Edit" button to add a key of type `wpa-pwd` with a value like `myPassword:mySSID`.

You might need monitor mode (promiscuous mode might not be sufficient). Also, make sure the device connects *after* you started monitoring (as Wireshark [needs the handshake packets to decrypt](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11)).

See also [these instructions](http://wolfhoundsec.blogspot.com/2010/06/monitoring-wpa2-wireless-traffic-w.html).

Comment: As per my earlier comment -- `I'm figuring the data would be encrypted, but ... I should still _see_ it, right?`: According to the link you posted as the answer - I'm correct. I don't see it, though. The link you posted notes: `Click "OK" to close the Capture Filter window and then click "Start" in the remaining window. You are now monitoring traffic flowing over your wireless network. However, the traffic is encrypted...` I don't see that.